# How to add &nbsp;, &gt; and &lt; into text in UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, character

My app need add string &nbsp;, &gt; and &lt; into text in UITextView so we can replace string in right place. We know that UITextView will change string &nbsp; to space, &gt; to > and &lt; to <. What should we do if want UITextView not change it into that character or how to add that string into UITextView?

Thank you before. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSString *)extractTextFromXML:(NSString *)xml{
//Will hold just the text
NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString string];
NSInteger startOfSubstring = 0;
//Finds first instance of "<"
NSRange startTagRange = [xml rangeOfString:@"<"];
while(startTagRange.location != NSNotFound){
    //Extracts text from last location up to "<"
    NSString *substring = [xml substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startOfSubstring, startTagRange.location-startOfSubstring)];
    //Removes whitespace from substring
    [text appendString:[substring stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];

    //Searches for ">" from "<" to end of string
    NSRange startTagToEndRange = NSMakeRange(startTagRange.location, [xml length]-startTagRange.location);
    NSRange endTagRange = [xml rangeOfString:@">" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:startTagToEndRange];
    //If ">" found, then sets next location of substring to after that
    if(endTagRange.location != NSNotFound){
        startOfSubstring = endTagRange.location+1;
    }
    //If no ">", then appends rest of string and returns
    else{
        [text appendString:[xml substringFromIndex:startTagRange.location]];
        return text;
    }
    //Finds next "<" in string
    NSRange endTagToEndRange = NSMakeRange(startOfSubstring, [xml length]-startOfSubstring);
    startTagRange = [xml rangeOfString:@"<" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:endTagToEndRange];
}

return text;
```

}

Or You can use UIWebView instead of UITextView

Comment: Thank you makboney for your answer. But, thats not I want. My last question is wrong. I have been edited it. Please read my question again. :)